# Automate Rest API test and integrate this with Continuous Integration(CI-Jenkins)

Tags: rest, jenkins, playframework, automated-tests, rest-assured

I found many similar questions related to this, but not the particular answer I am looking for. Actually my requirement is little different, so I end up posting the following issue.

I want to **automate Rest APIs**, and I got two options for the same case. 
The first one is `Rest Assured` and second one is `Play Framework`.

For example, to test this RestAPI:

```
http://servername:9000/dbs/all/list/m1/p1/sch1
```

(↑ This gives xml response)

So, I have written a code in `Java with Rest assured`, and is working fine. I integrate this with `Maven` project so that can be integrated with `Jenkins`.
Sample code:

```
   import com.jayway.restassured
    public class TestNGSimpleTest2 {

        @Test
        public void testApi() {
                expect().
                statusCode(200).
                body("Status", equalTo("Su22ccess")).
                when().
                get("http://localhost:9000/dbs/all/list/m1/p1/sch1");

        }
```

So my first question is:

1. Is the rest assured is the best tool to use?
2. Does Play framework is better?
3. I found many other tool like Jmeter, RightAPI etc. to test RestAPI. But I dont think this is automable. Am I right?

Comment: What let you think that tests created with automated testing frameworks wouldn't be "automatable"? Your question looks very strange to me...

Comment: If you have hard times configuring "heavy" frameworks, you may use lighter frameworks like [Frisby.js](http://frisbyjs.com).

Answer (score 6):

For automating REST API testing, as a starting point I recommend using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and [newman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/newman_intro).

Postman provides an excellent UI for building requests, and newman is its command-line counterpart. After you create a set of requests and corresponding tests within the Postman UI, you can run the entire collection from Jenkins via newman, preventing a deployment if tests fail.

Answer (score 4):

The RestAssured code you have posted will work just fine for basic cases. It's not necessarily the "right tool" if you want to:

- continuously add new test case and don't have many resources
- propogate alerts with well-formed error messages (especially to places like Slack or GitHub)
- reduce false-positives
- re-use the same tests for **monitoring**

Building these features takes time and resources which, depending on the size of your team may or may not be a good call.

Some of the commercial solutions you posted can solve some of these problems for you.

[Assertible](https://assertible.com) is a codeless solution that supports the workflow you described directly: https://assertible.com/blog/automated-api-testing-with-jenkins

Answer (score 1):

We can **integrate Jenkins and JMeter** for automating RestAPI testing.

The reason for that is,

- In Jenkins we can schedule our tests/builds in whichever way(every minute/hour/day/month.....) or based on the commits etc..
- we can bundle **n** number of APIs together in JMeter and execute in a single test.(Maintaining is easy)
- There is a **jenkins plugin "Performance"** which can be used to check the response time for each API call, which compares the response time with respect to the previous response times.
- JMeter has an **in-build threading feature**, which helps execute tests much faster than any single threaded tests.

Screenshots:
[image]

Steps

1. We can prepare our APIs in JMeter
2. Configure the tests in non GUI Mode in Jenkins.
3. Install and Configure the Performance plugin in Jenkins.